# combining jquery vTicker with getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, ticker

I have some code to get json data from another site like  this:

```
<html>
<head><script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/downloads/jquery.vticker.min.js>
</script>
</head>
<div id="example">
<ul class="row template">
        <li class="nohp"></li>
        <li class="content"></li>
        <li class="date"></li>
        <br/>
    </ul>
<script>
$(function() {

$.getJSON("http://1.handy-post-402.appspot.com/show?callback=?", function(json) {
console.log(json);
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    row = $(".row.template").clone();
    row.removeClass("template");
    var map     = json[i].propertyMap;
    var content = map.isi;
    var user    = map.No_HP;
    var date    = map.tanggal;

    row.find('.date').text(date);
    row.find('.nohp').text(user);
    row.find('.content').text(content);
    $("example").append(row);
}
$('#example').vTicker();
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to animated it with some vertical ticker like vTicker, but the page display nothing.
I've tried some example from [this](https://github.com/richhollis/vticker/blob/master/test/test_ticker.html) and modifying it but still didn't work.
any idea how to combine vertical ticker with code above?

vTicker is not a must so I'll accept any other recommended vertical function too.

--edited: I change the code into the didn't work one instead of just $getJSON function code

Comment: What's the problem here?  What did you try that didn't work?  Did you follow the example at https://github.com/richhollis/vticker?

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanks for the respond, I've tried the link above but didn't get any result as well. any idea how to use this ticker with json feed?

Comment: Why are you creating a new `<div>` (all with the same ID) and a new `<ul>` inside the `for` loop?  Look at the example (http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/) again and make sure to follow the way their HTML is.  Also remember that IDs *must* be unique on the page.  P.S. Do you want one scroller or three scrollers?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I've edited the code with modification from http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/, can you tell me what's wrong with this code? and btw I intend to make one scroller that display 2/3 list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vTicker plugin expects that you have a `<div>` with a `<ul>` inside.  What it will do is take all the `<li>`s there and scroll them.

You are not creating your HTML correctly for the ticker to correctly render anything.  You want to add a new `<li>` for each element you want scrolled.  You were close, but you should be doing it like this:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul class="row"></ul>
</div>
```

And then simply append the `<li>`s to it:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://1.handy-post-402.appspot.com/show?callback=?", function (json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var map = json[i].propertyMap;
            var content = map.isi;
            var user = map.No_HP;
            var date = map.tanggal;

            $('#example .row').append('<li>'+
                content + '<br>' +
                user + '<br/>' +
                date +
            '</li>');
        }

        $('#example').vTicker();
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/PFex7/